# How do I get Mew in Pokemon Fire Red?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I want to know if there is some way to obtain Mew in Pokemon Fire Red (Spanish version). I have the ROM emulated in my android phone (with My Boy Free). But there should be no difference between the real deal.

Answer (score 9):

There is no known way of obtaining Mew within FireRed or LeafGreen, outside of messing with the save data / memory / ROM yourself (i.e., cheating/hacking) or getting it by trading (i.e., an event). [There are no glitches that would enable a Mew encounter, either](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_glitches_in_Generation_III).